# Need advice with cheerio eq() variables

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

So i have this node.js script which scrape some parts of webpage:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var x = 1;
request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://balticnews.net/'
}, function(err, response, body) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('#table, td').eq(x).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

but i need that x would change. I tried to make a for loop but nothing changed. I need that when i run this program it would show me resuslts of x=1 then 1+5 after that 6+5  and so on and on its hard to explain :D Ofcourse i could just copy and paste this lots of times and choose numbers i need :

```
$('#table, td').eq(x).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

but i want to learn how to do it faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand you want just indexes : 1,6,11 ..probably a solution could be :

```
//Not tested
$('#table, td').each(function(index,element) {
     if(index%5==1){
        element.each(function(){
           console.log($(this).text());
       })

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a more generic solution in case of more complex case ?
(I'm in XML but same comment would apply to HTML inputs)

```
matchSeatIndex = $("mySeatList")
                .not(':has(SEAT > LIST_CHARACTERISTIC:contains("1"))')
                .has("SEAT > LIST_CHARACTERISTIC:contains('1W')")
                .has("SEAT > STATUS:contains('AVAILABLE')")
                .find('INDEX').first().text();
```

The problem here is that the first filter (on characteristic containing "1"), will also filter out the "1W".

---

In such a case, it is painful to write it in 2 parts

```
matchSeatIndex = $("mySeatList")
                .has("SEAT > LIST_CHARACTERISTIC:contains('1W')")
                .has("SEAT > STATUS:contains('AVAILABLE')")
                .find('INDEX').first().text();

//Then a second part to check with a function if the characteristic '1' is well present
```

Not sure why cheerio haven't implemented the :eq() there... Sounds basics.
Is there any trick doing the job ?